# Selenium standalone server is accessible only on localhost not on my IP's

Tags: macos, selenium, selenium-server

> SSS == 'Selenium Standalone Serwer'
>
> - I've got:
>
>   - installed SSS by homebrew
>   - downloaded couple versions of SSS
>   - macOS High Sierra with IP's:
>
>     - `192.168.0.1`
>     - `172.18.0.1 - IP for docker`
>     - `localhost/127.0.0.1`
>   - I have turned off my firewall
> - I run this server in one of the following ways:
>
>   - `selenium-server -port 4444`
>   - `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1.jar -port 4444`

after this, I've got logs:

> `2017-12-22 12:34:23.280:INFO:osjs.AbstractConnector:main: Started` `ServerConnector@210ab13f{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4444}`

so as I understand `0.0.0.0` it listens for all IPs
BUT
I can not connect to this server using IP `192.168.0.1` or `172.18.0.1`

I can use the only localhost for connecting to this server.
netstat doesn't display port 4444 as open.

When I do this same on `Ubuntu 16.04` it works great. I can create a new session using all addresses, I can create a new session also from docker container.

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong or what I don't know?

Comment: What if will you try the following `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1.jar -role hub`?

Comment: Can you update us if you are trying to start `Selenium Server` or `Selenium Grid Hub/Node`

Comment: Check you can ping 192.168.0.1 in cmd window;  Check if you set proxy, if so, add 192.168.0.1 into passby list

Comment: Sry for the late answer - I focused on the holidays with my children ;)
I am trying to use the selenium standalone server.
My computer rested during the holidays and after restarting everything started working ... o.O
I'm at work and I have another IP 10.xx.xx.xx and it works fine on it.
In the evening I will check the 192.168 ... it will also work.
I still can't use 172.18.0.1 - (this is gateway for Docker's containers) - but for this, I have to check Docker conf - I guess